# Set the bar origin in gauge indicator to start at 0 in plot.ly

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I would like to have the darkblue bar to start at 0, to be able to use it for negative and positive values.

Currently I don’t see how I could define that, judging by the reference.
https://plotly.com/python/reference/indicator/
https://plotly.com/python/bullet-charts/

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+gauge+delta", value = 10,
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    delta = {'reference': 10, 'position': "top"},
    title = {'text':"<b>Gearing</b><br><span style='color: gray; font-size:0.8em'>Finanical<br>Stability</span>", 'font': {"size": 14}},
    gauge = {
        'shape': "angular",
        'axis': {'range': [-100, 100]},
        'threshold': {
            'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 2},
            'thickness': 0.75, 'value': 70},
        'bgcolor': "white",
        'steps': [
            {'range': [-100, 100], 'color': "cyan"},
            {'range': [-50, 50], 'color': "royalblue"}],
        'bar': {'color': "darkblue"}}))
fig.update_layout(height = 250)
fig.show()
```

This is showing value=10

[image]

This is showing value=0

[image]

This is showing value=-40

[image]

Comment: Changing `value=0` would begin from 0 right?

Comment: no, value=0 would make the darkblue bar end at 0. It's start is in infinite negative I think.

Comment: So what are you looking for when value=0 and value =-40. How should the plot be?

Comment: the darkblue bar should not start from the left, but start from the middle position 0, so it only ever enters the negative area, when there actually is a negative value to show.

Comment: so at 0 marker, the darkblue should be present as well as value should be 0 right?

Comment: yes, the darkblue bar would be just a bare minimum stripe in the middle position at value=0.

Comment: Then change `reference:0`

Comment: reference:0 doesn't influence the 'bar', it is just a reference point for the red indicator number, showing wether we moved up or down in reference to an (old) value of 10 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to simulate the appearance that you want to achieve using only `steps`. What I did is to hide the `bar` setting `bar.thickness = 0` and then add an extra `step` with `step.range = [0, value]` and `thickness <= 1`.

I'm using Plotly.js, but the code should be similar.

```js
const data = {
  value: x
  type: 'indicator',
  mode: 'number+gauge',
  gauge: {
    shape: 'angular',
    bar: { thickness: 0 },
    steps: [
          {
            range: [-3500, 3500],
            color: 'cyan',
            thickness: 1,
          },
          {
            range: [-1200, 1200],
            color: 'royalblue',
            thickness: 1,
          },
          {
            range: [0, x],
            color: 'blue',
            thickness: 0.8,
          },
        ]
  },
}
```

[Negative value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPwD1.png)
[Positive value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am4Qe.png)

Comment: Thank you for this! I will try with dash, but yes it looks exactly like what I was looking for.